# Where can I get my horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On one of the loading screens of Skyrim, I saw a horse and it said that they are useful for long distance transportation in the Skyrim world. However, looking through the current big city I was in I was unable to find any horses! Do I need to catch them in the wild? Did I miss something?

Comment: Where can I get my horse armor?

Comment: @DoozierBlake: You should ask a new question for that, click "ask question" in the upper right corner. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look for the stables outside of the major cities. You can buy them there.

You can see where the stables are in relation to you (if there are any nearby) by keeping an eye out for the following horseshoe icon in your HUD compass:
[image]

They also show up with a similar icon on your map:
[image]

And finally, here's what the stables look like when you're in visual range:

[image]

You can also steal horses (found at stables or in the wild), but there's a 50 gold bounty placed on your head each time a guard is made aware of you mounting one. Stolen horses also run away when dismounted, while owned horses stay where you leave them.

Comment: Seems I can also find them in the wild or steal them according to Google, although I would rather have one soon than waiting for them to appear. A picture of such a stable would be nice; is the stable right outside the major city or rather somewhere between cities? I've only seen some watch towers and an abandoned town with some fights so far...

Comment: Added a screenshot and some clarification, thanks.

Comment: A good thing to note is that a stable icon appears on the bar at the top, I was playing and suddenly noticed that when running around the city rather than inside it. I don't think I have enough money to buy one yet so I hid inside the stable and stole the horse, I drove away and not a single $!@# was given... :)

Comment: As additional note the first horse that you will probable find, at Whirerun Stables, will cost 1000 gold.

Comment: FYI, you can supposedly find wild horses and take them as well as buying them.

Comment: Whassup with the courier?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a horse from Whiterun Stormcloack Camp just north of High Hrothgar, right under the mountain. Leaves when you dismount, comes back when you fast travel.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the opportunity to get a free white horse named Frost (if you succeed at a Persuasion attempt) at the completion of "Promises to Keep," a quest to retrieve ownership papers for said horse.  Look for Louis Letrush in the Bee and the Barb in Riften.

There's a second opportunity for a free horse on Katla's farm, south of Solitude. If you farm a bunch of leeks and potatoes and such for her to raise her disposition, she'll let you ride her horse(s) away, anytime you want.

Comment: Where do you get Frost's quest?

Comment: "Look for Louis Letrush in the Bee and the Barb in Riften."

Answer (score 0):

If you complete the quest *The Cure for Madness* from the Dark Brotherhood [(Spoiler)](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Cure_for_Madness) you'll receive *Shadowmere* as a reward.

Comment: Hi BeatMe, the question is asking how to do it in Skyrim, and it seems you thought it was Oblivion

Comment: Oh thanks. Skyrim does also have a quest with shadowmere as a reward, I did change the links. (But now the horses apparently are equal in hp and speed)