# Where can I get some armor for my magnificent steed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've [found my horse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35214/where-can-i-get-my-horse), but he's naked and is vulnerable. I know Oblivion had horse armor (as DLC) and I was wondering if Skyrim had the same. Failing that, is there anything I can do to keep my horse alive?

Comment: Voting to reopon. Not sure how this isn't a real question. Yes, it's a bit of a joke, but it's a completely answerable question. There is either horse armor in game (as there was in past games), or not.

Comment: I would think that might pop up in the skyrim workshop.

Comment: NM, quick search shows apparently not. However their are mods to make your horse more resilient or indestructible.

Comment: You should change the title to "Where Can I Get Some Armor For My Little Pony":)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no horse armour currently, because there is no mounted combat in Skyrim.

It *may* be released as dlc, as Todd Howard (jokingly?) said that it might be released as DLC like Oblivion.

Comment: Won't someone think of the poor, unarmored horses?

Answer (score 11):

No need to wait for another expensive Bethesda DLC. *Free* mods to the rescue:

### [Horse Armors for Skyrim](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=13348)

[image]

> This mod adds armored horses, replacing each cities buyable player horse with a unique armored horse. This mod is compatible with BETTER HORSES which adds horse STORAGE, horse invulnerability, and horse AI. The normal saddles are still used by NPCs.
>
> Whiterun: Nordic Steel Horse Armor
> Markarth: Dwarven Horse Armor
> Windhelm: Ebony Horse Armor
> Riften: LEATHER Horse Armor
> Solitude: Dragonbone Horse Armor
> Frost: Altered Model & Texture from Sader325's Divine Saint Mod

---

### [Hybrids Invincible Ebony Horse Armor for Skyrim](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=5526)

and **[Hybrids Invincible Dwarven Horse Armor for Skyrim](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=7882)**

[image]

> This mod will add horse armor to all horses that uses normal saddles, including Shadowmere. In addition, it will make armored horses invincible. These meshes were made entirely from scratch as well as textures with pieces taken from vanilla Ebony armors. This mod features the Ebony style.

---

[Search for horse armor mods at Skyrim Nexus here](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/searchresults/?quicksrc_name=horse+armor&quicksrc_auth=) (in case new mods come up).

Comment: Oooooooo classy

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the PC version, mods exist in the Steam Workshop that allow you to protect your horse. While there does not appear to be actual armor, you can render your horse invulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

As of the 2021 Anniversary Edition, steel and elven horse armors are officially available in Skyrim Special and Anniversary Editions. They are included in the Anniversary Edition, or they may be purchased for 250 credits each (as “Horse Armor - Steel” and “Horse Armor - Elven”) on the Skyrim Creation Club.

Comment: Your first sentence is misleading. They're available as paid mods for the anniversary edition; they're not part of the base game.

Comment: @roddy As the second sentence clarifies, they are included in the AE, or may be purchased individually on Creation Club. Available does not mean included in vanilla.

Comment: "As of the Anniversary Edition, horse armors are available as paid mods through the creation club." That makes it clear. You just say "available in Skyrim", which is actually, factually, wrong.

Comment: @roddy They are available (you can get them, though they are not included by default in the original or Special Edition releases) officially (curated/vetted by Bethsoft, don’t disable achievements) in Skyrim (via Creation Club off the main menu or included in the Anniversary Edition). Additionally, per the [Creation Club FAQ](https://creationclub.bethesda.net/en), it is inaccurate to call them paid mods.

Comment: No, you can't get them in Skyrim. You can get them on earth on your computer via creation club to use in Skyrim -- like any other mod.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas So 'Skyrim' the game, not 'Skyrim' the province (as "Skyrim Special and Anniversary Editions" implies).