# Where can I find the npc to buy add armor for my horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get some armor for my magnificent steed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35262/where-can-i-get-some-armor-for-my-magnificent-steed)

I think I'm supposed to talk to someone in the castles of the holds but none of the ones I've went to said anything about it? What city should I try and the name of the person I need to talk to would be great

Comment: What, you want *armor* for your horse?

Comment: You cannot customize your *horse*.  You can customize your *house*.  Was this a typo or a misunderstanding?

Comment: @StrixVaria Armored Warhorse. O yea. O yea.

Comment: yeah sorry armor for my horse

Comment: @tyler - Here, you say you want armor for your horse.  In another comment in this thread, you seem to say you want to furnish your house.  (Referencing a "booklet" that "says you can furnish it" - the only items matching this description being those about houses.)  Could you please edit the question itself to be clear as to which goal you're trying to accomplish?  If it's both, please edit this question to clearly address one and then create a separate question for the other.  As it is now, I'm not sure anyone here understands what you're asking.

Comment: Hopefully Skyrim will release DLC. [Horse Armor](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=horse%20armor) has always been every gamer's dream.

Comment: @Ender - The OP *specifically* said horses in a comment and others have provided answers as such.  Please do not edit questions in a way which invalidates other answers.

Comment: @desaivv - The only issue here was editing the question in such a way as to invalidate existing answers.  The OP *did* mention horses in the title and clarified [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52585/where-can-i-find-the-npc-to-buy-add-armor-for-my-horse#comment76520_52585)

Comment: @desaivv - Yes, it is quite obvious that the OP is misreading something somewhere, but it is still a valid (not good) question.  badp had closed this question on the grounds that the OP was changing his mind.  I pointed out that the OP *was* consistent and it was Ender who made it about houses.  When the question was reopened, it cleared the close flags.

Comment: Because you totally need armor for your *house*.

Answer (score 2):

As you travel from hold to hold you will find that each stable will have different horse breeds. The main difference is colour so travel to different hold and find different colours and patters. I think it may be random so i do not think that there are certain colours and patterns for each town you visit. The pattern and colour does not effect durability or attacking strength!

All horses cost 1000 gold in skyrim or you can overtake a fort for either the stormcloaks and imperials and at the end of the fight take the horse from the fort stables. This does not count as being stolen and once you ride it once it will stay with you.

Horses are not customizable but look around holds for various colours.

Comment: but in the booklet in the case it says you can furnish it

Comment: @tyler - You can furnish your *house*.

Answer (score 1):

You can't buy armor or equip one for your horse in the vanilla, un-modded game. If you're playing on the PC, you can try [mods to equip armor to your horse.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61253/4797)

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be all over the place now, but I'll try to address all concerns.

First, about horses and houses:  The capital cities for each major [hold](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Holds) ([Whiterun](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Whiterun), [Windhelm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Windhelm), [Riften](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Riften), [Solitude](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Solitude), [Markarth](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Markarth)) have both a house available for purchase and a stable.  The stables are located just outside the main city, and horses are always available for purchase at a price of 1,000 gp.  In order to purchase a house in the city, you are generally required to complete a quest for the Jarl, or another task of great significance to the hold.

**[Horses](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Horses)** come in many colors but, with only two exceptions, are all the same in regards to vital statistics such as speed, stamina, and health.  The two exceptional cases are not purchasable at stables - they are quest rewards.  [Frost](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Frost_%28horse%29) is faster than normal horses.  [Shadowmere](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shadowmere) has much higher health, regenerates health more quickly, and re-spawns a few weeks after death.  All the rest of the horses are generic, and none of the horses can be customized.  If you want a horse of a certain color, just shop around.

**As of 2/28/2012, there is no in-game method provided by Bethesda (out-of-the-box, or via expansions/mods) to armor your horse.**  There may be console commands or other hacks that can do this, but I don't consider those "in-game".  Some third-party mods may enable this functionality, but those would only currently be available for PC and are not "official".

**[Houses](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses)** come in varying sizes and prices.  All of the player-purchasable houses can be enhanced with certain modifications that add decor, storage containers, or other useful items.  The enhancements which are available, and their prices, vary between houses.  When you buy a house, you are given a "Home Decorating Guide" specific to that house which lists all the available upgrades but does not include pricing.  You can find out the prices by going to purchase the upgrades.

**All house enhancements must be purchased from the Jarl's steward in the same hold, who can usually be found in the Jarl's palace.**